# How to convert nsstring to float upto 2 decimal places in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When i convert **NSString** to **Float** upto `2` decimal places, it will automatically take `6` precisions after point. I want only `2` decimals after point. According to me, in `Objective-C` when we create a **Float** it will assign memory to store floating point number say `8` bytes.

So if i assigned `12.15` to a **Float** variable than, it will store `12.14999998` in that memory location and when i fetch that floating point number, it will fetch that number from that location and give it to me.

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: @KirtiParghi is you problem solve or not. if  yes accept the answer which you will really helps. if not solve then reply will try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to store float/double with an exact number of decimal, nor an exact value: that because of the internal representation of such value, in binary.

If you want such an exact value, you will need to use class `NSDecimalNumber`.

You init your number with:

```
NSDecimalNumber *myNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"12.87"];
```

And then, you can make your math on them using methods:

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumberByAdding:(NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumber
- (NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumberBySubstracting:(NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumber
- (NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:(NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumber
- (NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumberByDividingBy:(NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumber
```

and so on…

```
NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberSum = [decimalNumberA decimalNumberByAdding:decimalNumberA];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myFloat = round(myFloat*100) / 100.0;
```

this will get you rid of the extra decimals after the second position

Answer (score -1):

```
float num = 12.34555;
NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",num];
NSLog(@"sr %@",str);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try it...First convert `NSString` into  `float` then then give the %0.2f to get floating value upto 2 decimal points.

**Sample Code:**

```
NSString *string = @"3.45";
float floatValue = [string floatValue];
NSLog(@"%0.2f",floatValue);
```